# Where are "No" and "So" acceptable abbreviations for "North" and "South"

Tags: abbreviations

Driving around New York City on I-287 in Westchester County, the signs used to say

> No White Plains

for North White Plains. See, for example, [this picture](http://www.alpsroads.net/roads/ny/i-287/w7adv.jpg) from [this webpage](http://www.alpsroads.net/roads/ny/i-287/). 
They've recently replaced these signs with ones that say "North White Plains", probably because they confused tourists.

You also see signs "No Brunswick" and "So Brunswick" for North Brunswick and South Brunswick in New Jersey, southeast of NYC.

My understanding was that N. and S. were the standard abbreviations for "North" and "South". Where are "No." and "So." used? Is it just New York City and its suburbs, or is the usage more widespread than that?

Comment: In California the standard (abbreviated) geographical designations seem to be _NorCal_ and _SoCal_, but these short forms do not appear on highway signs.

Comment: In the UK signs north and south are either [written in full](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=road+sign+for+north+circular&biw=1366&bih=565&tbm=isch&imgil=8znzh_hrFxDuxM%253A%253BzktnDhN8TXT2TM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.geograph.org.uk%25252Fphoto%25252F1358018&source=iu&pf=m&fir=8znzh_hrFxDuxM%253A%252CzktnDhN8TXT2TM%252C_&usg=__iNyUBD2XatxOA-u4Pa6lYVZk13E%3D&dpr=1&ved=0ahUKEwiDtKP5vqTRAhUMD8AKHb0IAUoQyjcIJQ&ei=wtFqWIPLCYyegAa9kYTQBA#imgrc=8znzh_hrFxDuxM%3A)

Comment: or just [abbreviated N or S](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=road+sign+for+north+circular&biw=1366&bih=565&tbm=isch&imgil=0kySn-t0l2M9xM%253A%253B1J5QfxZEFn-F2M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.alamy.com%25252Fstock-photo-road-sign-on-the-a406-north-circular-road-at-the-waterworks-roundabout-41983005.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=0kySn-t0l2M9xM%253A%252C1J5QfxZEFn-F2M%252C_&usg=__s2bqqn81Aqh9afQa5z76VGVDT_Y%3D&ved=0ahUKEwiDtKP5vqTRAhUMD8AKHb0IAUoQyjcIJQ&ei=wtFqWIPLCYyegAa9kYTQBA#imgrc=G5DM91dZVavUlM%3A) The only other acceptable abbreviations would be "Nth" and "Sth".

Comment: @WS2: I think the same holds for most of the U.S. The "No White Plains" sign was quite confusing to me the first time I saw it.

Comment: Ireland is same as UK as described by @WS2. The *No* and *So* abbreviations look ridiculous to me!

Comment: @Sven: I think you get *SoCal* because it sounds better than *EsCal* or *SCal*. Ditto *NorCal*.

Comment: I think it might be a little old-fashioned here in the U.S.  Here are some examples: https://www.courtlistener.com/opinion/97361/so-pacific-co-v-interstate-comm-comm/, http://theweatherforums.com/index.php/topic/1384-is-no-atlantic-ground-zero-for-global-cooling/

Comment: I'd go with the more traditional first letter and last letter abbreviation as in Mister *Mr.* (Usually with a superscript second letter). So *Nh* sort of works but since the 'th' is often clumped together, *Nth*. *Nth.* is used all over the UK and I think is suitably clear to native and non-native English speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In American English, *No* **is** a "standard abbreviation"   for *North*.

For instance, see [American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=No), which gives the two-letter abbreviation with a period (*No.* or *no.*)

In Arkansas  the state capital (Little Rock) is contiguous to the city to the north called North Little Rock, and this latter is often abbreviated *No Little Rock* on street signs and addresses.

For example,  see [Snagajob](http://m.snagajob.com/jobs/arkansas/no_little_rock_jobs.html) and remember that in this context **No Little Rock jobs** doesn't mean there are no jobs in Little Rock; it's referring to jobs in North Little Rock.

And [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=no+st+paul+high+school) understands *No St Paul High School* to refer to the high school in North Saint Paul, Minnesota.

The phone number 308-526-xxxx is located in NO PLATTE, Nebraska. ([NPNR](http://npnr.org/308/526/)) That's North Platte, Nebraska.

I think the use of No (or No.) in such contexts is because a two character abbreviation is a bit longer and easier to read or harder to confuse, especially in hand writing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: *No* sounds eminently more likely to confuse people than a straight *N*. *No* means *No* (as the art mistress said to the gardener).

Comment: @WS2 I can see that   cities might prefer that if people are going to abbreviate an official  word of their city name, they don't abbreviate to something that is so common as to be used in directions or for streets (N 7th St). Just like anything else, *No* and *So* are not sources of confusion if one knows what they mean and the context.

Comment: Well, we all know what "no" means, don't we!

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw, the Neighborhoods around where my parent's live outside Phoenix use it (at least for parcels and mail). Such as: No. 154th Drive.

Answer (score 0):

> Where are "No." and "So." used?

In NoDak and SoDak muchly.

http://www.nodakelectric.com/

http://www.sodaklabs.com/

(no Olie and Lena jokes, please)

Less commonly in NoCar and SoCar

https://twitter.com/espnu/status/341785768898998272

Comment: What does *no Olie and Lena jokes, please* mean? Who are they?

Comment: I guess that Nocar refers to North Carolina, but if I were travelling as a tourist and I had never read the OP, I would be at a complete loss.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They are the northern plains states' contribution to humor. Easy to Google. I've lived in about twenty different states, including NoDak, NoCar, and SoCar. As I said in my answer, the usage isn't common in the Carolinas.